# Is there any way to get radians with asin/acos/atan functions JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, math, trigonometry, math.js

I'm currently using Math.js library to process math equations.

I know is possible to change from radians to degrees using "deg" or "rad" withing the trig function sin(), cos(), tan(). But for arcs functions asin(), cos(), tan() it doesn't seem to work.
If there any other way around except from manually calculating it.

```
test= math.eval("sin(1 deg)"); //Works
test2 = math.eval("sin(1 rad)"); //Works

test3= math.eval("asin(1 deg)"); //Does not work
test4 = math.eval("asin(1 rad)"); //Does not work
```

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/math-asin-javascript/

Comment: @King Stone Could you explain ?

Comment: I think, javascript support `Math` class, and we can use `Math.asin(1)`.  We don't need any library for `asin` function

Comment: Yes i know but I am using it

Comment: @EXMark2 The JS built-in `Math` class is not the same thing as this Math.js library you are using.

Comment: Yes but i use it for another part of my application. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to trig functions (and return value from inverse trig functions) is a number in *radians*.  To use degrees, multiply or divide by by `Math.PI/180`.

```
Math.sin(45 * Math.PI/180) --> -.7071...

Math(Math.arctan(1)) * 180/Math.PI --> 45 (degrees)
```

If you are working with radians, don't multiply or divide by that factor.

```
Math.asin(1) --> 1.57...  (radians)
Math.asin(1) * 180/Math.PI -->  90   (or something close; in degrees)
```

Comment: I was actually converting the value inside asin(), that's why I was getting the wrong result. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should use,

```
math.eval("asin(1)");
```

Arcsine is an inverse trigonometric function using number as input value

As [documentation](https://mathjs.org/docs/reference/functions/asin.html) refers, asin(x) requires *number* value which *deg* is not.

Comment: Is there any way to get the radian value of 1 using asin()?

Comment: arcsin(sin(1)) is what you want as I undersand right?

Comment: @alpsavrum - that would give a value near 1.000, and it is radians.  `asin` and `sin` are inverses of one-another.